# Resource not found error for vector drawable in android 5 and 5.1

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, android-5.1.1-lollipop

**Hi,
I am using binding adapter methods to pass 1 imageUrl and 1 placeHolder drawable in image view like this.**
[image]
**and my binding adapter method is like this:**

[image]

**and here is my vector drawable:**

[image]

**it works perfectly fine for android 10 API level 30, and crashing for android 21 and 22 (as far I have tested ) giving resource not found error error:**

[image]

**Please help**

Comment: so Android 21, 22 could not handle those vector icon, using PNGs solved the problem.
Need to find a way to use vectors only, as it takes very less memory compared to pngs.